# React Native, problemas con arranque y error con login de instagram

Tags: reactjs, react-native, instagram, yarn

tengo un problema con el arranque de un proyecto en react native, os paso las pantallas a ver si podeis decirme que pasa.

despues de comprobar que el dispositivo físico está conectado con adb devices ejecuto yarn android, y esto es lo que sucede.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esto es lo que pasa con node

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ejecuto yarn add react-native-instagram-login, pero no logra conectar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tiene pinta de que no tienes instalado bien el módulo react-native-inatagram-login

Comment: entiendo, y como se puede instalar correctamente?